# BeautifulSoup: get_text() returns empty string from bs4 Tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract information from [this news page](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/oct/20/boris-johnson-could-be-held-in-contempt-of-court-over-brexit-letter).

First I parse the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/oct/20/boris-johnson-could-be-held-in-contempt-of-court-over-brexit-letter")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Then I start with the title:

```
title = soup.find('meta', property="og:title")
```

and if I print it, I get:

```
<meta content="Boris Johnson could be held in contempt of court over Brexit letter" property="og:title"/>
```

However, when I run `title.get_text()`, the outcome is an empty string: `''`

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there actually isn't any text defined by the tag. The "text" you are after in this case, is contained in the `<meta>` tag with the attribute `content`. So you need to pull out the value of `content`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/oct/20/boris-johnson-could-be-held-in-contempt-of-court-over-brexit-letter")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('meta', property="og:title")['content']
```

**Output:**

```
print (title)
Boris Johnson could be held in contempt of court over Brexit letter
```

You can get all the attributes and values by using `.attrs`. This will return a dictionary (key:value pairs) of the attribute and value within the given tag:

```
title = soup.find('meta', property="og:title")

print (title.attrs)
```

**Output:**

```
print (title.attrs)
{'property': 'og:title', 'content': 'Boris Johnson could be held in contempt of court over Brexit letter'}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Would it be possible to get the whole list of elements? Not just `['content']`, but to see them all?